# In a Slack, is there a way to see all the members that is part of that channel?

Tags: slack

In a Slack, is there a way to see all the members that are part of that channel? I created a channel example #groundzero but I couldn't tell who is in it? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to SuperUser.com

Comment: Please take the [Tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the documentation in the [Help Center](//stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, you should read about [how to ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what sorts of questions are [on topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.

Comment: Posted on the wrong Stack Exchange site but still a good question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the right top corner, to the left of the search bar, there is `Show Channel Details` switch, that shows and hides channed details sidebar, including members list.

Comment: Note, this no longer works, it now lets you "search" for members. `/who` still works.

Answer (score 30):

Another very quick way to get the users of the current channel is to use the `/who` command.

Just enter that command in the any channel and Slack will tell you which users are member of that channel. And the command and response will only be visible to you.

See [here](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201259356-Using-slash-commands) for a list of all build-in commands in Slack.

Comment: Fantastic! It's cool stuff like this that makes Slack stand out from other messaging platforms.

Comment: looks like the returned list is throttled at 30 users

Comment: Funny that /who isn't listed in the link you shared.

Comment: Looks like /who is capped at 99 for me, displays: list of some names, "you and XX others! (Check the channel details to view the full list of members.)